# JQuery effect is stuttering when loading a YouTube iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, youtube

I am very new to JS/JQuery/JQueryUI but have made a few things work on a new site I'm working on.

I've set up a basic navbar where a `.click` makes different `div`s slide into view with `.show` while the other three pop out of existence with `.hide`. I was extremely proud of myself even though this is super basic.

My issue is that one of these `div`s contains a YouTube `iframe`. To get it to stop playing when another `div` is shown, I just remove the `src` with `.attr` (clunky, I know). This means that since the source is re-appended to the `iframe` each time, going back to that `div` is slower than I want it to be, and jQuery stutters.

I've put a stripped down version into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stavro510/shhq0xq1/2/). Any suggestions on improving the performance would be greatly appreciated!

PS: The video I have as a placeholder is hilarious and you should enjoy it! :)

HTML:

```
<div class="button" id="home">1</div>
<div class="button" id="about">2</div>
<div class="button" id="latest">3</div>
<div class="button" id="contact">4</div>

<div class="home"><iframe class="video" id="homeVid"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gspaoaecNAg?controls=0?showinfo=0?rel=0?enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="content about"></div>
<div class="content latest"></div>
<div class="content contact"></div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    width: 600px;
    height: 480px;
    display: none;
    clear:both
}

.home, .video {
    width: 600px;
    height: 480px;
    display: flex;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #CCC
}

.about {background-color: #F00}
.latest {background-color: #0F0}
.contact {background-color: #00F}

.button {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlhome = $('#homeVid').attr('src');
    $('#home').click(function() {
            $('.home').show('slide', {direction: 'right', easing: 'swing'}, 400);
            $('.about, .contact, .latest').hide(0);
            $('#homeVid').attr('src', urlhome);
    });
    $('#about').click(function() {
            $('.about').show('slide', {direction: 'right', easing: 'swing'}, 400);
            $('.home, .contact, .latest').hide(0);
            $('#homeVid').attr('src', ' ');
    });
    $('#latest').click(function() {
            $('.latest').show('slide', {direction: 'right', easing: 'swing'}, 400);
            $('.home, .contact, .about').hide(0);
            $('#homeVid').attr('src', ' ');
    });
    $('#contact').click(function() {
            $('.contact').show('slide', {direction: 'right', easing: 'swing'}, 400);
            $('.home, .about, .latest').hide(0);
            $('#homeVid').attr('src', ' ');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, adding and removing the iframe is costly in terms of performance. Instead we must stop the playback and hide it.

This necessitates to insert it differently into the document, using the [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Then we do this:

HTML

```
<div class="content home">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
var player;
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function(){

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '480',
        width: '600',
        videoId: 'gspaoaecNAg',
    });
});
```

We can simply use `player.stopVideo();` whenever we hide the `home` element. But if only it was so simple.

Using jQuery's [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) has side effects, because the way it hides elements is by setting their CSS to `display:none` which effectively removes them from the document. This destroys the iframe and recreates it on [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), which presents the same performance issue as before.

We need something more subtle, hiding the elements by putting them aside. For this we use positionning:

```
.hidden {
    position:fixed;
    left:200%;
}
```

This puts them further on the right of the document, outside the viewport and since the units are relative, it can never be vsible no matter how much we stretch the window. This necessitates a few changes in HTML, plus some others for an optimization I will detail further below.

HTML:

```
<div class="button" id="home">1</div>
<div class="button" id="about">2</div>
<div class="button" id="latest">3</div>
<div class="button" id="contact">4</div>

<div class="content home">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
<div class="content about hidden"></div>
<div class="content latest hidden"></div>
<div class="content contact hidden"></div>
```

We have added the class `hidden` to all elements not visible at the start. We also added a class describing the elements themselves and set to the `id` of their corresponding button. And we have the `content` class in each element.

JavaScript:

```
var player;

$(window).load(function(){

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '480',
        width: '600',
        videoId: 'gspaoaecNAg',
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var all = $('.content');

    $('.button').click(function() {

        all.addClass('hidden');

        player.stopVideo();

        $('.'+this.id).animate({
            'left': '0px', 
            easing: 'swing'
        }, 400, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hidden')
                .removeAttr('style');
        });
    });
});
```

This has been optimized to avoid checking each element individually. The first part has been explained before, here is how the rest goes:

1. `var all = $('.content');`
   This selects all the `.content` elements and keeps them referenced outside the callback in the variable `all`, so we only have to do this once when the document loads.
2. We create the callback on all `button` elements. The next step assumes a click event has been received.
3. We set all `.content` elements to hidden. Effectively this should only affect the one currently not hidden.
4. We stop the video. This will only affect the embedded iframe and we don't bother checking which `.content` element is active because stopping an already stopped video does nothing special.
5. Using the `id` of the button that triggered the `click` event, we select the corresponding `.content` element.
6. We replace [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) with [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and use it to modify the CSS property that is used in the class `hidden`. This will slide the element from its hidden position to it's normal position.
7. The animation has a callback executed when it's done. We use it to first remove the `hidden` class from our now visible element, then to remove the `style` attribute in which our animation has set `left:0px;`, as leaving this there would interfere later.

And we're done. This should now be smooth. A demo is available on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shhq0xq1/8/).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed! I won't be back home til tonight when I can check it all out, but I really appreciate the detailed feedback. Will mark as Answered once I get things moving tonight

Comment: Everything seems to be working! Your explanation made me FINALLY understand the basics of the YouTube Player API. Thanks so much, @spenibus